# magento join order and invoice

Tags: php, magento, join

Basically I want to link sales/order and sales/order_invoice table to get order_source feild from sales/order when cycling through invoices;

This is my attmpt:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->getCollection();
$collection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('from' =>$from));
$collection->joinAttribute('order_source', 'order/order_source', 'order_id', null, 'left');

foreach($collection as $invoice){  

$orderSource = $invoice->getOrderSource();

//do other stuff

}
```

I'm new to magento

Comment: order_source is a custome attribute i added

Comment: That `joinAttribute` looks good to me. Can you explain what is wrong?

Comment: @clockworkgeek I could not access the variable i.e. it was always `null`, I figured out the problem when I tried to sort as it gave me an error messages:  `Fatal Error:... Main_table.order_source not found ....` (you were right there was no problem with the `joinAttribute`)

Comment: Maybe it's because order entities are not EAV. That often trips me up too.

Comment: Have a look on the contents of joinAttribute in this case. It is just "return $this"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(technically not a correct answer  just another way of doing it)

I used `join` instead below is what I used:

```
$collection->join(array('order' => 'order'), 'order.entity_id=order_id', array('order_source'=>'order_source'), null , 'left');

$collection->addAttributeToSort('order_source', 'DESC');

foreach($collection as $invoice){  

$orderSource = $invoice->getOrderSource();

//do other stuff

}
```

hope it helps someone

p.s to get all attributes from order you could use the following: (but not recommended because of optimization of `*`):

```
$collection->join(array('order' => 'order'), 'order.entity_id=order_id', array('order'=>'*'), null , 'left');
```

and to get specific fields use:

```
$collection->join(array('order' => 'order'), 'order.entity_id=order_id', array('some_feild'=>'some_feild', 'some_other_feild' => 'some_alies_for_other_feild'), null , 'left');
```

and then use `$collection->getSomeAliesForOtherFeild()` and `$collection->getSomeFeild()`